# Package Does Not Exist - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java so please forgive me if this has a simple solution (and I hope so though). I have added previously coded .java class files to my existing project in eclipse, while trying to import com.abc. and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> it even shows these packages and classes.

However when I try to compile it says "package xxx does not exist". I've spent hours researching on this but most of the solutions focus on .JAR files and I don't have a jar file. I even tried creating a .JAR file and then importing but I think I couldn't manage to success that.

I really need help about this and thanks for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand how to add jar files in eclipse project. You can place you're jar files in webinf lib folder.
And after that you can configure the project build path. By

```
Right click on project (in eclipse project explorer) > buildpath > you find configure build path.
```

Comment: Can't I simply use without adding JAR file? I just want to use these classes in my project.

Comment: Add those java classes into this project, before adding it create a packge with the name com.abc and add those classes in this package.

Comment: Nope. Still no luck. When type "import com.abc" and press ctrl+space it even suggests me my newly added classes, however when I compile it still gives error. This is really annoying.

Comment: [javac] C:\test\com\abc\filename.java:16: package com.abc.newfile does not exist
However I noticed that if I copy these class files to same directory as old files it works (com.abc), but I need to create a sub directory as com/abc/newfile/ so I can put new class files to there.

Comment: Simply create a package with name com.abc.newfile and place java file in that

Comment: Or go to my computer project > src > create a folder with name com in that create a folder with abc in that create newfile folder and place your kava file in newfile folder and refresh your project in eclipse

Comment: It looks as project>src>com>abc>newfile>javaClass.java

Comment: Thanks for your help but still no luck. There must be something I am missing.

Comment: @BurakS did you find a solution to this? Even i am facing similar problem