# Getting an error that Package does not exist in eclipse java [ERROR]

Tags: java, eclipse, json-simple

I am getting an error that package does not exist in Eclipse Oxygen Java even though the package is imported I looked at this link: [Package Does Not Exist - Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330975/package-does-not-exist-eclipse). This did not help me. The .jar is in my build path but when I build it still gives errors. I'm using the JDK 8, and seem to get the error on json-simple.jar. OS: windows 10. The jar is in build path classpath variables and checked already in the order and export.

[PICTURE OF THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvglF.png)
 [ANOTHER PICTURE OF THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J6Yu.png)

Comment: You're going to have to provide much more detail. You haven't given us enough information to see what might be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a list of things you could try:

- File -> Restart
- Right click on project -> Refresh.
- Project -> Clean
- Project -> Build Project
- Remove the .jar from the project classpath, then add it again.

This happened to me once and I did File -> Restart, and the error was gone. If none of these work, then the .jar was probably compiled incorrectly. Hope this helps.

Comment: That did not work